# All the zero values in upper triangle

Tags: r, matrix

I've got the following code:

```
afs_in_sound <- stringdistmatrix(soundexcode_termen, soundexcode_termen, method = 'hamming')
```

My matrix looks as follows:

```
   0   1   inf   inf  
   1   0    0    inf  
   inf 0    0    inf   
   inf 0   inf    0
```

I want to get all the indices for which the value is 0 in the upper triangle matrix. So here I want [2,3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
which(upper.tri(afs_in_sound) & afs_in_sound==0, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Which gives :

```
     row col
[1,]   2   3
```