# How to find the index of zero elements in upper triangle matrix in a cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, find, cell-array

I want to find the index of zero elements in the upper triangle of the matrix inside a cell array. Assume that I have a cell array `A{1,1}` and there is a matrix `B` of size *19*-by-*19* inside the first cell of `A`. How can I find the index of `0` elements on the upper triangle of the `B` matrix?

I tried to use the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216195/all-the-zero-values-in-upper-triangle) and I wrote this code:

```
which(upper.tri(Adjecany_Valid_vertices{1,1}) &   Adjecany_Valid_vertices{1,1}==0, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

but it didn't work for me and it gives me an error:

> The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

does anybody have any solution for finding these requested zeros?

Comment: The code you posted is ***r*** code so of course it doesn't work in ***MATLAB***!!!

Comment: Please provide actual example data (that one could simply copy and paste into MATLAB to get the exact data structure). Instead of a *19*-by-*19* matrix, use a smaller example like say a *5*-by-*5*. Include the manually calculated output that you want as well.

Comment: @Dan, THX Dan. randomGuy's answer solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A{1,1}` is not a cell array, it is one cell in a cell array 'A'. But your question does not really have to do anything with cell arrays. Your question is how do I find the indices of all zeros in only the upper triangular part of a matrix. The code you are looking for is:

```
idx = triu(B==0)
```

`idx` will be a two dimensional matrix of logicals with true wherever the element is zero. All the entries in lower triangular part will be false. You can use this matrix like

```
t = B(idx)
```

to get all the zero elements as a single column array. If you want to get indices in an `i,j` format you would have to do:

```
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(B), find(triu(B == 0)))
```

I would suggest looking up `triu`, `ind2sub` and `find` in the documentation